# smallest sigma algebra on $R^2$, that makes function $A - B^1$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I have a function: $f: R^2 -> R$

$f(x,y) = I_{[0,\infty)}(x) * I_{[0,\infty)}(y) + I_{[0,\infty)}(x + y)$

I want to find smallest sigma-algebra on $R^2$, that makes this function $A - B^1$ measurable.

I came up with the following smallest sigma algebra: $T = [R^2,[0,\infty),\emptyset] $

Am I right? If yes, should I prove it(how?) or it's enough to leave it as it is.

If not, give me a hint how should I approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $T$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, since $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus [0,\infty)^2\notin T$.

Your $f$ only attains finitely many values, i.e. $f(x,y)\in\{0,1,2\}$. Try to find the sets $f^{-1}(\{k\})$, for $k=0,1,2$ and build your $\sigma$-algebra from there.